# Is the Google IKEv2 DH cipher modp_2048s256 the same as Cisco DH group 24?

Tags: vpn, gcloud, cisco, tunnel

This question is specific and only concerns Google Cloud VPN.

Google Reference https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers

Cisco Definition (group 24) https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/diffie-hellman-groups/ta-p/3147010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. The DH group numbers can be found in the [IKEv2 registry at IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ikev2-parameters/ikev2-parameters.xhtml#ikev2-parameters-8) and the *modp_1024s160*, *modp_2048s224*, *modp_2048s256* represent groups 22, 23 and 24, respectively.

Please note that the use of these groups has been discouraged by [RFC 8247](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8247#section-2.4):

> Groups 22, 23, and 24 are MODP groups with Prime Order Subgroups that
> are not safe primes.  The seeds for these groups have not been
> publicly released, resulting in reduced trust in these groups.  These
> groups were proposed as alternatives for groups 2 and 14 but never
> saw wide deployment.  It has been shown that group 22 with 1024-bit
> MODP is too weak and academia have the resources to generate
> malicious values at this size.  This has resulted in group 22 to be
> demoted to MUST NOT.  Groups 23 and 24 have been demoted to SHOULD
> NOT and are expected to be further downgraded in the near future to
> MUST NOT.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if their documentation provided the group number like this:

- 1024-bit w/ 160-bit prime order subgroup = Group 22
- 2048-bit w/ 224-bit prime order subgroup = Group 23
- 2048-bit w/ 256-bit prime order subgroup = Group 24

It's easy to confuse Group 24 with Group 19, which is in the more widely supported ECP family:

- 256-bit Elliptic Curve = Group 19
- 384-bit Elliptic Curve = Group 20
- 521-bit Elliptic Curve = Group 21